# Generating data for the creation of a plot in R

Tags: r, function, plot, machine-learning

I started with the task to replicate a plot that I have seen in a study. 
When trying this, however, I was puzzled by how it was created.

This is what the plot looks like:

[image]

The "x" in the plot represents the percentage of countries with a certain score (let's say all countries that have score ==1). The two lines represent the percentage of two other independent variables.

Now what I know is that the dataset looked something like this (this is just a sample -- very similar to the structure of my dataset as well).

```
country year    x1  x2  score
A       1990    0   0   0
A       1991    1   0   1
A       1992    1   0   1
A       1993    0   0   0
A       1995    1   0   0
A       1996    1   0   2
A       1997    1   0   0
B       1990    0   0   0
B       1991    0   0   0
B       1992    0   0   1
B       1993    0   0   2
B       1995    0   1   2
B       1996    0   0   2
B       1997    0   1   2
C       1990    0   1   2
C       1991    1   1   0
C       1992    1   0   0
C       1993    1   0   0
C       1995    1   0   0
C       1996    0   0   1
C       1997    0   0   1
C       1998    1   1   0
D       1990    0   0   2
D       1991    0   0   2
D       1992    1   1   2
D       1993    1   1   0
D       1995    0   0   1
D       1996    0   0   1
D       1997    0   0   1
```

As you have see above, the `score` variable is an ordinal variable with the values 0, 1, and 2. I would like to create a data frame that would allow me to plot in a similar way as the plot displayed above. This is where I'm puzzled as to how to proceed. My questions below are based on the assumption that I need to do the following in order to plot a similar graph.

How do I calculate the percentage of states with score ==0  and the corresponding percentage of x1 and x2 for states with score ==0

Ultimately, I will need to do the same calculation for countries with score==1 and score==2.

I need some input – so I appreciate all suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get a percentage of some condition (e.g., % of score == 0) is using `mean(condition) * 100`. Here's a detailed blog post about it: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/proportionsfrequencies-with-mean-and-booleans. Note to use `mean(condition, na.rm = TRUE) * 100` if you have missing values.

I'll start with simulated data that roughly matches what you've provided:

```
set.seed(987)
d <- data.frame(
  year  = rep(c(1991:2000), each = 10),
  x1    = sample(c(0, 1, 2), 100, replace = TRUE),
  x2    = sample(c(0, 1, 2), 100, replace = TRUE),
  score = sample(c(0, 1, 2), 100, replace = TRUE)
)
head(d)
#>   year x1 x2 score
#> 1 1991  1  2     2
#> 2 1991  2  1     2
#> 3 1991  1  1     2
#> 4 1991  1  0     2
#> 5 1991  2  0     0
#> 6 1991  0  0     1
```

Then you can use `group_by(year)` and `summarise(...)` from `dplyr` package to compute the percent of times you observe a particular score for each year:

```
library(dplyr)
to_match <- 0
d <- d %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(
    x1    = mean(x1 == to_match) * 100,
    x2    = mean(x2 == to_match) * 100,
    score = mean(score == to_match) * 100
  )
d
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>     year    x1    x2 score
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   1991    10    60    30
#> 2   1992    60    20    30
#> 3   1993    40    40    30
#> 4   1994    40    50    50
#> 5   1995    50    50    20
#> 6   1996    30    40    20
#> 7   1997    20    30     0
#> 8   1998    20    60    40
#> 9   1999    40    30    20
#> 10  2000    20    40    40
```

Note, I just set the variable `to_match` to `0`. You can change to 1 and 2 for other values.

Then, you can plot with `ggplot2` with something like:

```
library(ggplot2) 
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1991:2000) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x1)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x2), color = "grey") +
    geom_point(aes(y = score)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
    ylab("Percent Countries") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want a legend and are happy to make all geoms the same (i.e., all lines and/or all points) you can use `gather()` from the `tidyr` package to get into long format, then change the `group` and `color`/`linetype` aesthetics in the plot to match. Here's an example:

```
library(tidyr)
d %>% 
  gather(-year, key = "var", value = "Percent") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = Percent, group = var)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1991:2000) +
    geom_line(aes(linetype = var, color = var)) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
    ylab("Percent Countries") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Simon – thanks for this. Great blog! One problem: NA's in my real data, how do I control for them in the code? Also,  just to be sure: I don't need to put the "country" variable in the code, right? "to_match" does the all job?

Comment: Can add `na.rm = TRUE` into `mean()` to handle missing values (I'll add a comment in the answer). Re "country", I don't see a need unless you have a country appear more than once per year? And thanks re blogR feedback!

Comment: Great – thanks for all the work you've put in. Yes, the blog looks really nice, I'll explore it more tmr.

Comment: One very useful thing would be to have a little window in the plot explaining the names of the plotted variables.

Comment: Example with a legend added.

Answer (score 2):

I used your example data below in dat. Perhaps there is also a more vectorized way of doing this, but it works. This only does it for score, but it is straightforward to extend it to x1 and x2 as well.

```
# get unique score values and unique years
uniqScore = unique(dat$score)
uniqYear = unique(dat$year)
# assuming total number of countries remains constant
totalCountries = length(unique(dat$country))
# empty matrix to store results
store = matrix(NA, length(uniqYear), length(uniqScore))

# loop over unique scores
for (i in 1:length(uniqScore)) {
  # loop over unique years
  for (j in 1:length(uniqYear)) {
    # find the number of observations with a given year and score
    # subsequently divide it by the total number of possible countries
    # to obtain a percentage and save it in store
    store[j, i] = length(dat[dat$year == uniqYear[j] & 
                               dat$score == uniqScore[i], 1]) / 
      totalCountries
  }
}

# plot results
matplot(uniqYear, store, type = 'b', pch = 1:3, lty = 2, bty = 'n', las = 1,
        ylab = 'Percentage', xlab = 'Year')
legend('topright', legend = uniqScore, pch = 1:3, lty = 2, col = 1:3, bty = 'n')

# or to make it into a dataframe
df = data.frame(percentage = c(store), 
                score = rep(uniqScore, each = nrow(store)))
```

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: A more parsimonious way to get `store` may be `tab1 <- xtabs(~score+year, dat)` followed by `store <- t(apply(tab1, MARGIN=2, function(x) x/totalCountries))`.